# Proving path connectedness (simple)

Tags: general-topology, multivariable-calculus, path-connected

> Let $L=\left \{ (x,0)\in \mathbb{R}^{2}~:~x\geq 0 \right \}$. Prove that $\mathbb{R}^{2}\setminus L$ is path-connected.

It's easy to see why this set is path connected. I'm just not sure how to show it rigorously. Also how would I go about showing a set is not path connected?

Comment: My edit was for a typo "Let $=$..." to "Let $L=$..."

Comment: Not being path-connected can be subtle. Let $X=A\cup B$ where $A=\{0\}\times [-1,1]$ and $B=\{(x,\sin(1/x): 0<x\le 1/\pi\}.$ This is called the Topologist's Sine Curve. $X$ is connected but not path-connected. You can find proofs on this site.... BTW individual Q's here are accessible to a Google search-by-topic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For each $p\in\mathbb R^2\setminus L$, the line segment from $p$ to $(-1,0)$ is a subset of $\mathbb R^2\setminus L$. So, given a second point $q$, you have a path in $\mathbb R^2\setminus L$ from $p$ to $(-1,0)$ and another one from $(-1,0)$ to $q$.

And the simpler way to prove that a set is not path connected is to prove that it is not connected.

Comment: How would I show $\mathbb R^2\setminus P$ is not connected, where $P=\left \{ (x,y)\in \mathbb R^2 :y=x^2 \right \}$

Comment: @Loobear23 This set is the union of the disjoint open sets $\{(x,y): y >x^{2}\}$ and $\{(x,y): y <x^{2}\}$